# Bottom Overflowed By Pixels and does not working navigate function

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile-application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oc0M.jpg)

The above photo shows the error what i have facing .bottom is overflowed 484 pixel and also navigation is does not working in sidebar . then i coudn't able to find the error.

```
class MyHeaderDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHeaderDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 200,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height:80,
                width: 80,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("img/logo.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Text(
                "Travel With Me",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const Text(
                "info@findpath@gmail.com",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 106, 105, 105), fontSize: 10),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 70,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text('My TODO'),
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text('My Time Table'),
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.timeline),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text('Notification'),
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.notification_add),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                
                    ),
                  
                    const Divider(color: Colors.black),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text('About Us'),
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                      onTap: () => {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const About()),
                        )
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text('Privacy and policy'),
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.privacy_tip),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const PrivacyAndPolicy(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

why we cannot use onPresed() , insted of Using onTap(). i need to resolve my problem .could you please help me .

thank you!

chamithu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

```
return SafeArea(

      
      child: Column(
       
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 200,
          child: Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
             Container(
            height:80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              
            ),
               child: Placeholder()
          ),
          const Text(
            "Travel With Me",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const Text(
            "info@findpath@gmail.com",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 106, 105, 105), fontSize: 10),
          ),
          ])),
         
          
         Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('My TODO'),
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                  onTap: () {
                   Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('My Time Table'),
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.timeline),
                  onTap: () {
                   Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Notification'),
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.notification_add),
                  onTap: () {
                   Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
            
              
                const Divider(color: Colors.black),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('About Us'),
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                  onTap: () {
                   Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Privacy and policy'),
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.privacy_tip),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            )
          ]

    ));
```

Comment: Genius_balu its working brother thank you